# Flask Deploy VPS Apache

Tags: python, apache, flask

I start Flask with the command python3 init.py and the page is accessible by IP address, then I want the page to be constantly running using apache to do all possible manipulations, create the wsgi file, add the config to the Apache folder, restart the Apache, the page does not appear. Tell me where is the error? I feel that I am calling incorrectly or indicating the paths incorrectly.
In the example, the domain folder is replaced by me specifically.

Did everything according to the instructions https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

What am I doing wrong?

````
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName мой_домен.ru
        ServerAdmin admin@мой_домен.ru
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/jointproject/data/www/мой_домен.ru/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/jointproject/data/www/мой_домен.ru/FlaskApp/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/jointproject/data/www/мой_домен.ru/FlaskApp/static
        <Directory /var/www/jointproject/data/www/мой_домен.ru/FlaskApp/static/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
=============================================================================
flaskapp.wsgi

    #!/usr/bin/python
    import sys
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
    sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/jointproject/data/www/мой_домен.ru/")

    from init import app as application
    application.secret_key = '6036037'
===========================================================================
init.py 

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, I love Digital Ocean!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host = '109.248.11.175')```
````

Comment: What's the error you are seeing in the browser? Is your WSGI wrapper generating a log file (wfastcgi.py that I use for IIS does, but you need to set an env variable to enable) and if so are there any errors in the log file?

Comment: @IanAsh Hello!
When navigating to a domain address, I see only http://prntscr.com/rk7x5l
If I run python __in __. Ru then I see a running application with the inscription "Hello, I love Digital Ocean!" . wfastcgi.py does not create.


YA uzhe chto  tol'ko ne pereproboval.
Mozhet mne v fayle wsgi nuzhno zapuskat' ne init fayl?
Struktura proyekta http://prntscr.com/rk7znc
131/5000
I just have not tried it.
Maybe I need to run the non init file in the wsgi file?
Project Structure http://prntscr.com/rk7znc and http://prntscr.com/rk806s

Comment: I can't help much other than tell you it's definitely an Apache config issue as the screenshot shows that Apache is just delivering the folder to the browser and not trying to run/route to Python/Flask at all.

Comment: I have the same problem and I still cannot fix it - If anyone knows how to fix this, please help